# Can one shot from a shotgun apply multiple on-crit effects?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

Shotguns produce 10-20 pellets with each shot, depending on your distance to the target and spread, only part of them can hit the target. Does it mean that only part of them can crit, or is it all-or-nothing? If the former, can one shot with a few pellets critically hitting trigger multiple on-hit effects, like "Cold and calculating" (Chance to get the Cold Blood on crit)?

EDIT: After a bit of testing, I can say that:

1. Multiple pellets can crit individually
2. You can get multiple stacks of cold blood from that critical hits (if you have the "Cold anc calculating" skill)

Comment: After your edit, it looks like you've answered your question?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas only partially as in my build I can't test all possible on-crit effects.